# How to whitelist people without restarting the server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a server and I want to be able to add people to my whitelist from inside the server so that I dont have to restart the server though when I type in what I have to:

```
/whitelist add username_of_person_to_add
```

It just says that I dont have permission even though I am a level in the OP.json file

I have tried changing the level that I am an OP though it hasn't helped

Comment: You need to add yourself as op from the server console or ops.txt (I think) before you can use commands like `/whitelist`

Comment: Are you using any permissions plugins or vanilla Minecraft? Some more detail about your server setup would be very helpful and assist in getting the question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it with the same code though in the gui

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is type in console is
"whitelist add username"

If you can not do that,

http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/permissionsex/

Create a group,

```
  Admin:
    default: false
    build: true
    permissions:
    - '*'
```

If you create a group set it to false If you want only certain people to have it or true if anyone can have it.

In console type "pex user add [USERNAME] group add Admin"

If you do not have that try /reload